# How to set NOT NULL constraint for data table at AWS athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to know how to set CONTRAINTS over data table on AWS Athena.

I'm a beginner who just started learning about database and AWS.

I could find out that I can set contraints over data table(e.g.,PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL) through dbms like postgresql.

However, I could not find how to set constraints over data table by querying at AWS athena.

It seems that athena does not support contraints mapping. Is there any other ways to set constraint for data on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Athena is based on [Presto](https://prestodb.io/)/[Trino](https://trino.io/) (depended on the engine version, also [Trino is the new name for PrestoSQL](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)), which is not a database, but as [description](https://trino.io/docs/current/overview.html) says:

> Trino is a distributed SQL query engine designed to query large data sets distributed over one or more heterogeneous data sources.

Trino does not maintain primary keys, constraints, indexes and so on. See also [use cases](https://trino.io/docs/current/overview/use-cases.html) and [Trino concepts](https://trino.io/docs/current/overview/concepts.html).